# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called with Apigee SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apigee, apigee-baas

I've been trying to register for push notification using Apigee SDK, but on some devices iPhone 5 and 6 don't receive push Notifications. More specifically, neither UIApplication delegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

or

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

are not called.

I got this error when try to send the push notification

There was a problem delivering all of your notifications. See deliveryErrors in properties",
     "state": "FAILED",
     "deliveryErrors": [
       "No devices for notification e438f4ca-4b46-11e5-8eb8-..."
     ],

I register with :

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            // iOS 8 and higher
            [self registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
            [self registerForRemoteNotifications];
        } else {
            // iOS 7 and lower
            [self registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        }
```

On some devices the register is successful but in others not.

Comment: Are you certain you've allowed notifications from your app to each device? A deny will persist across app installs.

Comment: I am also on the project and yes the notifications are allowed on the app. We get this on about 1% of installed devices and we were just able to replicate on one of our own devices. Notifications were coming in and then stopped when we installed a version with more debug code. Weird thing is that you SHOULD at least get one call to either one of the delegates, but it does not happen.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - only thing I can think of is either the device registration failed or it wasn't mapped at all. Are you able to add your URI including query params for one that fails?